# Importing oracle dump file to remote server from Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, fedora

I have an Oracle dump file. I want to import this file to a remote oracle server. How can I import an Oracle dump file to remote server from Linux?

Comment: You really should at least try to find the answer before posting here, google for impdp utility. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL300

Comment: Agree with user J91321 - the Oracle docs should be reviewed.  If you want a quick start guide this may help - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-jul/datapump11g2009-quickstart-128718.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can reach the remote oracle server you want to import to -- in this example `db1` -- then here is a generic (minimal) example of a full import:

```
impdp user/password@db1 full=Y directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=db1.dmp logfile=db1.log
```

Without knowing any more specifics this is the best that can be offered.